# Not able to return one record from controller get by Isbn

Tags: java, json

I am working with spring and json data I have loaded the json into the spring bean with this config

```
@Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
        @Bean
        Book books() throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("book.json"), Book.class);
        }
    }
```

And here is my controller that should return one data when i perform get by ISBN

```
  @GetMapping(value = "items/{isbn}")
    public Item getItem(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn) {
        for (Item item : book.getItems()) {
            for (IndustryIdentity industryIdentity : item.getVolumeInfo().getIndustryIdentifiers()) {
                if (industryIdentity.getIdentifier().equals(isbn)) return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When i test it on postman and curl the result is a bunch of data instead of just the data with such isbn number

Myjson looks like this

```
{
  "requestedUrl": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=java&maxResults=40",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "7tkN1CYzn2cC",
      "etag": "pfjjxSpetIM",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/7tkN1CYzn2cC",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "A Hypervista of the Java Landscape",
        "publisher": "InfoStrategist.com",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9781592432172"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "1592432174"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": true,
          "image": true
        },
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "1.0.1.0.preview.3",
        "imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "language": "en",
        "previewLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&pg=PP1&dq=java&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
        "infoLink": "http://books.google.pl/books?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&dq=java&hl=&source=gbs_api",
        "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape.html?hl=&id=7tkN1CYzn2cC"
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "PL",
        "viewability": "PARTIAL",
        "embeddable": true,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.pl/books/download/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape-sample-epub.acsm?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": true,
          "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.pl/books/download/A_Hypervista_of_the_Java_Landscape-sample-pdf.acsm?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
        },
        "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=7tkN1CYzn2cC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
        "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      }
    }
```

This is the curl

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/items?isbn=9788131754559
```

Comment: Does the path `items?isbn=9788131754559` matches the path `items/{isbn}`? Have you checked that the method you thing should be called is actually called?

Comment: @JBNizet generally i have about 40 items ( This items are books)  but when i perform get by Isbn number it returns all the 40 items

Comment: You haven't answered my questions. Does the path `items?isbn=9788131754559` matches the path `items/{isbn}`? Have you checked that the method you thing should be called is actually called? Hints: the answers are no, and no :-)

Comment: I think its not actually called because i used http://localhost:8080/items?isbn=randomdigits and it still returns all the data

Comment: You **should** be able to **know** that it's not being called. Use your debugger. Or add System.out.println() to the method. Or replace the method body by `throw new RuntimeException()`. Again: Does the path `items?isbn=9788131754559` match the path `items/{isbn}`?

Comment: Yes it matches  i have just two methods in my controller getAll and getByIsbn So i have this path as written above items/{isbn} then in Postman i tried localhost:8080/items?isbn=339839839

Comment: So, to you, the pattern `items/{isbn}`means: "items, followed by a question mark, followed by the string isbn, followed by an equal sign, followed by an isbn"? Don't you think it rather means "items, followed by a slash, followed by an isbn"?

Comment: The reason i used that is i done that before and it worked, but now i changed it to / and  it calls the method. Please when do we use the question mark ?

Comment: Also it shows that it calls this method but result is empty while there should be a record

Comment: When you use a RequestParam, and not a PathVariable. Now that you finally know that your method is called, and know which correct URL to use, debug your method to understand why it returns an empty result.

Comment: So what i found out is it returns the correct data when i use @RequestParam but with PathVariable the method gets called but doesnt find the result and returns empty